# Excel string function not returning value

Tags: string, excel, function, vba

I have difficulties understanding what's wrong in my code.
The function is not returning any value. When I ask the debugger to stop on the last line  & Verif_toutes_erreurs = result, it does not stop. 
I don't understand the reason why, do you ?

```
Function Verif_Toutes_Erreurs() As String
Dim RESULT As String
Dim CELLULE As Range
Dim LISTE As String
Dim TEMP As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

For Each CELLULE In SheetCoutRH.Range("Table_CoutRH").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
TEMP = SheetCoutRH.Cells(CELLULE.Row, SheetCoutRH.Range("Table_CoutRH").Column)
    If InStr(1, LISTE, TEMP) = 0 And i < 10 Then
    LISTE = LISTE & TEMP & ";"
    RESULT = RESULT & "La ligne " & TEMP & " contient une erreur." & vbCrLf
    i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > 9 Then Exit For
Next

For Each CELLULE In SheetIngredients.Range("Table_ing").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
TEMP = SheetIngredients.Cells(CELLULE.Row, SheetIngredients.Range("Table_ing").Column)
    If InStr(1, LISTE, TEMP) = 0 And i < 10 Then
    LISTE = LISTE & TEMP & ";"
    RESULT = RESULT & "La ligne " & TEMP & " contient une erreur." & vbCrLf
    i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > 9 Then Exit For
Next

For Each CELLULE In SheetRecettes.Range("Table_ing").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
TEMP = SheetRecettes.Cells(CELLULE.Row, SheetRecettes.Range("Table_recettes[Recette]").Column)
    If InStr(1, LISTE, TEMP) = 0 And i < 10 Then
    LISTE = LISTE & TEMP & ";"
    RESULT = RESULT & "La ligne " & TEMP & " contient une erreur." & vbCrLf
    i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > 9 Then Exit For
Next

Verif_Toutes_Erreurs = RESULT

End Function
```

Than your a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a breakpoint is "avoided" when is not reached by the execution flow. :-)

If your function exits prematurely by error (for example, invalid worksheets), the last line will never be reached. If you call the function from another sub/function that contains a permissive error handling like `On Error Resume Next` before function call, then the error will be silently ignored by the runtime, and the function will "act" like it didn't returned anything.

Comment: arf, I forgot the on error resume next from the other sub calling this function... Thanks !!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Your function has no arguments.**

If the function appears in a worksheet cell, its lack of arguments will inhibt it being called.  The simplest fix is to include:

```
Application.Volatile
```

as the second line of the function.